# Typescript: Definition file for index.js reexporting React Component is empty export

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollup, .d.ts

I want to use Typescript to generate declaration files for my non-typescript React component library, using JSDoc for setting the types of the props. The JSDoc part works fine, but there is something I just can’t get to work about the `.d.js` files.

My component library is structured like this:

- There is a component file: `/MyComponent/MyComponent.jsx`, which has a default export that is a React function component (`export default function MyComponent({children}) { return <div>{children}</div>; }`
- There is an `index.js` file next to the component, that reexports the component: `/MyComponent/index.js` contains `export { default } from './MyComponent.jsx';`
- There is a general `index.js` file that reexports all components: `/index.js` contains `export { default as MyComponent } from './MyComponent';`

I’d say that’s a pretty standard file structure for a React component library.

I generate the `.d.ts` files with this `tsconfig`:

```json
{
  // Change this to match your project
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "outDir": "types",
    "lib": ["ES6", "dom"],
  }
}
```

These definition files are generated:

- A  file for the general index: `/types/index.d.ts` – `export { default as MyComponent } from "./MyComponent";`
- A file for the component: `/types/MyComponent/MyComponent.d.ts` – `export default function MyComponent({ children }: { children: any; }): JSX.Element;` (this is a simplification, for my real components it contains the typings for props, etc.)
- A file for the index for the component: `/types/MyComponent/index.d.ts`. **This file, however, instead of reexporting the Component, just contains an empty export: `export {};`.**

When I try to use [rollup-plugin-dts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-dts) to rollup my `.d.ts` files into a single file, it fails: `Error: 'default' is not exported by types/MyComponent/index.d.ts, imported by types/index.d.ts`.

This, of course, makes a lot of sense given that `types/MyComponent/index.d.ts` does in fact not export anything.

I just can’t find out how I can get it to reexport the definition file for the component. Am I wrong in thinking that it should? How can I get a single `d.ts` file with the typings for my component library?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that all imports from `.jsx` files were ignored by the typescript compiler. To solve it, I had to add `"jsx": "react"` to my `tsconfig`:

```js
{
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "outDir": "types",
    "lib": ["ES6", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

I had not done that before, because I thought it is only necessary when you want typescript to compile your `jsx` for you, which I didn’t need, but it is also necessary to get `jsx`-files aknowledged in the declaration files.